# how to run flask application from lambda_ function

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda

I am trying to run Flask application from lambda_handler function, but unable to do the same.
Initially I was getting the time out error. But afterwards I have tried doing the same using the below approaches in lambda _handler function.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Pass the incoming event to your Flask application using the request context
    response = app.full_dispatch_request(request.event, request.context)

    return {
        'statusCode': response.status_code,
        'headers': dict(response.headers),
        'body': response.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    }
```

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Create an instance of your Flask application
    app_instance = app.create_app()

    with app_instance.app_context():
        response = app_instance.full_dispatch_request(request.event, request.context)

    return {
        'statusCode': response.status_code,
        'headers': dict(response.headers),
        'body': response.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    }
```

Get the error message: "'Flask' object has no attribute 'create_app'",

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    with app.app_context():
        response = app.full_dispatch_request(request.event, request.context)

    return {
        'statusCode': response.status_code,
        'headers': dict(response.headers),
        'body': response.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    }
```

```
def lambda_handler(event, context, app=app):
    flask_request = request.FlaskRequest(event)

    response = app.full_dispatch_request(flask_request)
    return {
        'statusCode': response.status_code,
        'headers': dict(response.headers),
        'body': response.data.decode('utf-8')
    }
```

Error Message: "Working outside of request context.\n\nThis typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed\nan active HTTP request.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    with app.test_request_context('/'):
        # Pass the incoming event to your Flask application
        response = app.full_dispatch_request(request)

    return {
        'statusCode': response.status_code,
        'headers': dict(response.headers),
        'body': response.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    }
```

Error: "full_dispatch_request() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Can anyone please help me to resolve this? and please point out if any of the above approach is inappropriate.
Thanks

Comment: see Zappa to run flask on lambda functions: https://github.com/zappa/Zappa